# Generic Binary Search Tree Java type argument is not within bounds

Tags: java, generics, search

I did the following binary search tree but it doesn't work... need help

```
class Tree<ContentType extends Comparable<ContentType>>{


  Node node;
  public Tree(){
    node = null;
  }
  public Tree(ContentType pContent){
    node = new Node<ContentType>(pContent);
  }
  public Tree(ContentType pContent, Tree pLeftTree, Tree pRightTree){
    node = new Node(pContent);
    node.setLeftTree(pLeftTree);
    node.setRightTree(pRightTree);
  }
  public boolean isEmpty(){
    ...
  }

  public void insert(ContentType pContent){
    ...
  } 

  public ContentType search(ContentType pContent){
    ...
  }

  public void delete(ContentType pContent){
    ...
  }
  public ContentType getContent(){
    ...
  }


...      

    private class Node<ContentType>{
        Tree left = null;
        Tree right = null;
        ContentType content = null;


        public Node(ContentType pContent){
          content=pContent;
          left = new Tree();
          right = new Tree();

        }

        ... 

    }


}
```

Now it tells me

```
type-variable Content-Type#1 is not within bounds of type-variable Content-Type#2.
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: Where and when does the exception appear?

Comment: when i want to compile the program it shows it in console

Comment: `public Tree(ContentType pContent, Tree pLeftTree, Tree pRightTree)` should probably be `public Tree(ContentType pContent, Tree<ContentType> pLeftTree, Tree<ContentType> pRightTree)`. Didn't you get any warnings about using raw types? - Besides that I'd suggest using more distinct names for generics since `ContentType` could be mistaken for a classname.

Comment: I run the code above (only the given one) and it worked for me ...

Comment: the problem pops up in the method getLeftTree

Comment: so in the Node class there is a public Tree<ContentType> getLeftTree() and this Content Type is wrong since the compiler is right :D

Comment: @RiekRudolph so your problem is solved?

Comment: no it isnt... i need to know how to solve the following now:

Comment: ContentType#1 extends Comparable<ContentType#1> declared in class Tree.Node
    ContentType#2 extends Comparable<ContentType#2> declared in class Tree

Comment: `the problem pops up in the method getLeftTree` - it might help if you posted that method then (and don't do so in a comment but edit your question please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fully fixed class file - make sure to specify the generic types when declaring all instances of a type!

```
class Tree<ContentType extends Comparable<ContentType>>{

    // here
    Node<ContentType> node;

    public Tree(){
        node = null;
    }

    public Tree(ContentType pContent){
        node = new Node<ContentType>(pContent);
    }

    // each time Tree is used, it should be typed!
    public Tree(ContentType pContent, Tree<ContentType> pLeftTree, Tree<ContentType> pRightTree){
        // same with Node!
        node = new Node<ContentType>(pContent);
        node.setLeftTree(pLeftTree);
        node.setRightTree(pRightTree);
    }

    //Node needs to be typed with the exact same type as Tree!
    private class Node<ContentType extends Comparable<ContentType>>{
        // Typed Tree!
        Tree<ContentType> left = null;
        Tree<ContentType> right = null;
        ContentType content = null;


        public Node(ContentType pContent){
            content=pContent;
            left = new Tree<ContentType>();
            right = new Tree<ContentType>(); 
        }

        public void setLeftTree(Tree<ContentType> tree) {
            left = tree;
        }

        public void setRightTree(Tree<ContentType> tree) {
            right = tree;
        }
    }
}
```

And to compile w/o warnings:

```
~ bfung$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_40
~ bfung$ javac Tree.java
~ bfung$
```